# Flutter google_maps_flutter not working in app

Tags: flutter

I am using google_maps_flutter in my app. I have followed exactly all steps to create API enable the SDK android to generate the key. Paste key in androidmanifest.xml  But don't know why I am getting these errors.

```
W/PlatformViewsController(26149): Creating a virtual display of size: [1080, 2296] may result in problems(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2897).It is larger than the device screen size: [1080, 2224].
I/zzbz    (26149): Making Creator dynamically
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Unsupported class loader
I/DynamiteModule(26149): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203112999
I/DynamiteModule(26149): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203112999
V/DynamiteModule(26149): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/Gralloc3(26149): allocator 3.x is not supported
I/DynamiteLoaderV2Impl(26149): [71] Mapsdynamite
I/Google Maps Android API(26149): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API(26149): Google Play services package version: 204265037
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149): java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):6)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):1)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):24)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):2)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aW(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):18)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at ds.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):4)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:19)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:13)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:22)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.onCreate(GoogleMapController.java:515)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.init(GoogleMapController.java:110)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapBuilder.build(GoogleMapBuilder.java:35)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapFactory.create(GoogleMapFactory.java:49)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:186)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:423)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:317)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:250)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.<init>(VirtualDisplayController.java:95)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:48)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:207)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7584)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26149):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/eveloper.pet_u(26149): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/eveloper.pet_u(26149): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=765 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
E/flutter (26149): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml, null, java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):6)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):1)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):24)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):2)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aW(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):18)
E/flutter (26149):  at ds.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204265081@20.42.65 (120400-0):4)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:19)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:13)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:22)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.onCreate(GoogleMapController.java:515)
E/flutter (26149):  at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
E/flutter (26149):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
E/flutter (26149):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.init(GoogleMapController.java:110)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapBuilder.build(GoogleMapBuilder.java:35)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapFactory.create(GoogleMapFactory.java:49)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:186)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:423)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:317)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:250)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.<init>(VirtualDisplayController.java:95)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:48)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:207)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (26149):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/flutter (26149):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7584)
E/flutter (26149):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/flutter (26149):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
E/flutter (26149): )
E/flutter (26149): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
E/flutter (26149): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.da
```

I haven't changed a single code from the plugin but it's showing too many errors don't know it's a plugin issue or what because not able to find any good one.

Need to know what can I do now? Because I have done all things doublecheck key, recreate google cloud project